# How to fill a listbox with an array filled in module1 VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, listbox

I'm new to creating user forms in VBA. I've been using VBA macros for a while now though so I understand some about them. Right now I'm creating a spreadsheet for a user where I'm using a user form with a list box. I have a lot of code in a regular module and need to refernce the module to fill the listbox. What I have right now is this:

```
Private Sub StartButton_Click()
 Dim Number
 Call GetTellerNames
 For Number = 0 To 40 Step 1
    If GetTellerNames(Number) <> "" Then
        ListBox1.AddItem (GetTellerNames(Number))
    End If
 Next
End Sub
```

When I run this I get an error saying

> Sub of Function not defined

How do I fix this so that I can use the array in my module to fill the list box? I've already got the code to fill the array working.

Here is the code for the GetTellerNames sub in the module:

```
Private Function GetTellerNames()
GetTellerNames = FindOthers(BranchNumber, TellerCode, 2)
End Function
```

It is using global variables that are set in other parts of the code. I can post all of the code if necessary.

Comment: Can you post your code for `GetTellerNames`? You probably don't need `Call GetTellerNames`, as `GetTellerNames` seem to require a parameter. Or do you mean something like `InitializeTellerNames` for the first call?

Comment: `Private Function GetTellerNames()
    GetTellerNames = FindOthers(BranchNumber, TellerCode, 2)
End Function` This is the code for GetTellerNames. It's in the module and is using the global variables set in other parts of the code.

Comment: where is your `GetTellerNames()` function located? Is it within the userform object module or a standard code module?

Comment: change the access modifier from Private to Public ( or remove the Private as Public is default ) see if that helps recognize the function

Comment: you can try to qualify the function too Module1.GetTellerNames() but avoid using Call if the function is returning something.

Comment: It is in a regular code module. Now I feel like an idiot though, didn't even realize it was private. That's just what I've always used, I don't usually have more than one module. @mehow If you put that into an answer I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: Apart from the `Private`as pointed out by mehow, your code is still strange: in the function definition you just provided, you do not accept a parameter. Yet, you call it with `GetTellerNames(Number)`. Shouldn't it be something like `Public Function GetTellerNames(Number as Integer) As String`? In this case, also remove the first `Call GetTellerNames`!

Comment: Also, I'd recommend using `Option Explicit` - this way you avoid plenty of errors! See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DeclaringVariables.aspx

Comment: @PeterAlbert good point since there is no support for method overloading in VBA

Comment: @mehow: one of the many features I miss in VBA... :-(

Comment: @PeterAlbert yep it soon will be time to move onto C#, COM libraries and VBA extensions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `GetTellerNames()` code lies within a standard module you need to change the access modifier to *`public`* in order to be able to access that method/sub from the UserForm1 object module.